# cannot find /usr/bin/env while running pig

Tags: cygwin, apache-pig

I have installed cygwin to run pig on windows. But it is showing following error.

```
$ pig -x local
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What exactly is pig and how did you install it?

Can you run /usr/bin/env bash from your command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Have you add pig to your PATH ?

Could you try with the absolut path :

```
/Users.../pig-12.1/bin/pig -x local
```